# How to copy and NOT overwrite the file in Win7?

Tags: windows-7

I have a folder in the network drive which I need to download from to my computer to work. The folder is large and I had copied some yesterday. When I tried to download the rest, win7 just asked me whether I wanted to overwrite the existing folder. It did not give me an option of "copy and keep the file if the names are the same". Please help. Thanks

Comment: To make the situation more clear, the folder have many sub-folders, and each sub-folder has many sub-folders.

Comment: Windows should [ask you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ADDZ4.jpg) if you want to *merge* the folders. If you say yes, it will ask again if there is a conflicting sub-folder, but you can click the checkbox at the bottom to merge all conflicting sub-folders. It should also [ask you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2lOOW.png) if you want to overwrite the conflicting files. Likewise, you can click the checkbox at the bottom of the dialog, and select no (`Don’t Copy`) to have it copy all of the non-conflicting files and ignore the conflicting ones. Do you not see these dialogs?

Comment: How exactly are you downloading them? Are you using Explorer?

Comment: How I can do a merge option?

Comment: Simply copying a file in a folder and pasting the copy in the same folder will give you the chance to create a new file with a different name.  Why isn't that an option?

Comment: @Ramhound I have so many files that I don't want to download again

Comment: @Marco, you don’t. When you initiate the copy operation, Windows will detect if there are any conflicts with the folder and offer you the option of merging the folder or not. With file conflicts, Windows will offer you the option of overwriting the existing files, renaming the new files, or skipping them altogether. It’s unclear what is happening. Please take a screenshot of what is happening and add it to your question so that we can diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Marco - Download?  You asked how to copy a file and not overwrite the file I just told you.  You can skip the files that already exist within the same dialog.

Comment: @Ramhound The 1st sentence in the message "I have a folder in the network drive which I need to download from to my computer to work."

Comment: Ok but you skip the files you already have

Answer (score 1):

You could use Robocopy which by "default" will skip all files that already exist at the destination. Robocopy is included with Windows 7.

To use Robocopy, open a "Command prompt" window... the basic syntax of Robocopy is:

```
robocopy "D:\source\path" "D:\destination\path" OPTIONS
```

For a full list of Robocopy options, view Robocopy "help" by typing:

```
robocopy /?
```

Some options to use:

```
/S        also copy subdirs of source to destination (do not copy empty subdirs)
/E        also copy subdirs of source to destination (include empty subdirs)
/COPY:DAT copy D(ata) A(ttributes) and T(imestamps) for copied files
          [other /COPY: options are available]
/DCOPY:T  copy T(imestamps) for copied folders
/XJ       exclude copying of "Junction-Points"
/ETA      show estimated time remaining while copying which may or may not be helpful
/L        do not actualy copy anything, only show files that "would" be copied
          [useful to "test" your Robocopy command line before actually copying files]
(Many more options are available for Robocopy operation)
```

(Note: `/COPY:DAT` is the default case, so you can omit this... I have included it in these examples for clarity since you will have to include it if you are using other "/COPY:" options).

So, a possible Robocopy command line you could use might be:

```
robocopy "S:\network\path" "D:\local\path" /E /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /XJ /ETA /L
robocopy "S:\network\path" "D:\local\path" /E /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /XJ /ETA
```

Run it once with the "/L" option to view which files will be copied. Then if all looks good, run it again without the "/L" option to do the copying (if you're brave, skip the "/L" altogether).

For more information about the options for Robocopy see this other post I wrote about Robocopy:
https://superuser.com/a/566054/144147, which includes external links to more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer - but couldn't you just go into the folder on the network drive, select all files and copy these to the same folder on your pc? Then you will be asked if you want to overwrite the files rather than the folder - answer being no of course.

Comment: Too many files, so may not work

Comment: The only other suggestion I have for you would be to do it in blocks..copy all starting with a-e, then f-j, etc.. that way you will at least know where you are up to. Network drives often do behave in slightly peculiar ways.. I am sure there will be free software that could be downloaded that will do what you ask - am sure I used one called "file commander" once upon a time - perhaps someone else knows one or two?

Comment: @Mark, that wouldn’t work since there are sub-folders. They would practically be manually copying each file individually at that rate.